# How to get Entry Id for a Newly Created Entity in Breeze

Tags: angularjs, breeze

i want to create a registration form that will be in batch with a continuation button, getting the id of the entry will help me to call the save method.

I want to immediately get the primary key of a new Entry Created using BreezeJS, Pls i need help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you want to get the id of a newly saved record immediately after the save. If so then the answer below applies.

When the save promise resolves it returns both the list of saved entities as well as a *keyMappings* array for any entities whose ids changed as a result of the save. i.e. a mapping from temporary to real ids. i.e. (Documented here: http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_saveChanges)

```
myEntityManager.saveChanges().then(function (saveResult) {
  // entities is an array of entities that were just saved.
  var entitites = saveResult.entities;
  var keyMappings = saveResult.keyMappings;
  keyMappings.forEach(function(km) {
    var tempId = km.tempValue;
    var newId = km.realValue;
  });
});
```

On the other hand if you have an entity and you just want its 'key' you can use the *EntityAspect.getKey* method. (see http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityAspect.html#method_getKey)

```
// assume order is an order entity attached to an EntityManager.
var entityKey = order.entityAspect.getKey();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i will work on the implementation.